# Is there a way to use `sf::st_join` to get the proportion of area captured?

Tags: r, r-sf

I want to use:

`st_join(polygon_A, polygon_B, join=st_intersects)`

to get the same output as of the current version with an extra column that specifies the proportion of the area captured from `polygon_A` by `polygon_B`? Ideally this would work with `largest=TRUE` (returning unique records of `polygon_A` with only one match from `polygon_B`) or with `largest=FALSE` (returning all matches from `polygon_B` with the proportions of captured areas by `polygon_A`).

My workaround was to use `st_intersection(polygon_A, polygon_B)`, calculate the area of the new shapes (the result of the intersection) using `st_area`, and then divide it by the area of the original shape of `polygon_A`. Is there a better way of achieving this? Or maybe plans to add this as a feature to `st_join`.

For the record and to avoid the [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem), my objective is to identify cases where the proportions are close to 0.50/0.50 or 0.70/0.30 and take a closer look to decide if `largest=TRUE` is meaningful. I am not very interested in cases where the proportions are 0.99/0.01 - `largest=TRUE` is good enough for these cases.

Comment: That's basically what I do. It isn't too burdensome if it's all in one pipe: `mutate` to get area of 1st shape, `st_intersection`, then `mutate` to get area of intersection and percent covered by intersection. But I suppose you could wrap those steps into a function easily enough. `st_join` wouldn't be the place for it, since the geometry returned is the same as the left-side `sf` object as far as I'm seeing